# Identification of ultrafilters with measures

Tags: gn.general-topology, ergodic-theory, ultrafilters

We know that each ultrafilter $p$ on $\mathbb{N}$ can be identified with a finitely additive $\{0,1\}$-valued probablity measure $\mu_{p}$ on the power set of $\mathbb{N}$.

Now my question is which conditions should be added to a topological space $(X,T)$ to provide a situation for it's Stone-Chech compactification to identify each ultrafilter $p$ on $X$ with a measure $\mu_{p}$ on the power set of $X$ (or the sigma-algebra of Borel subsets of $X$)?!

Also it's possible for this measure to has some properties.

Comment: Needs more explanation.  Does the definition of "ultrafilter" on a topological space have something to do with the topology?  There is a measure characterization of realcompact spaces that may (or may not) be what you want here.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I have encountered with this question in reading of Vitaly Bergelson survey on Ergodic Ramsey theory during the process of defining Stone-Cech compactification. Where  can i find what you said at the end of your comment?!

Comment: This great book that every student of analysis should read ...  L. Gillman & M. Jerison, *Rings of Continuous Functions*

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @GeraldEdgar what will be happen if we change to this: which conditions on Ston-Chech compatification of $X$ achieved from ultrafilter.?

Comment: I edited my question. We should speak about Stone-Chech compactification

Comment: @GeraldEdgar By what you said and searching that book in the case that our space is realcompact i.e. completely regular Hausdorff space with real elements of Stone-Chech compactificartion there is an identification.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is what you're looking for, but you have an isomorphism between $\ell_\infty$ and $C(\beta\mathbb N)$ and, consequently, isomorphism between the duals. This is also described in the Wikipedia article on [Stone–Čech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#An_application:_the_dual_space_of_the_space_of_bounded_sequences_of_reals). See also the answers here: [The Duals of $l^\infty$ and $L^{\infty}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47395).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I am searching for a kind of method to achieve a measure from an ultrafilter or vice versa

Comment: An ultrafilter on any set $X$ amounts to a finitely additive $\{0,1\}$-valued measure on the power set of $X$. That is, what you wrote about $\mathbb N$ is true for all sets.  I suspect, though, that you didn't really intend to ask about ultrafilters on arbitrary set but rather about points in the Stone-Cech compactification of arbitrary completely regular spaces.

Comment: @AndreasBlass By your first sentence maybe the second one is a better choice to search about it.